# How to compare value and delete from firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase realtime database in Android app, and have data like this:

[image: This is my database]

How can I access that data from javascript.
I just wanna code function to get value of every endTime and compare with current time and if endTime <= Current Time then delete values yellow marked on anther image.

[image: Yellow Marked Values]

Events is fixed value.

Indjija, Vojvodina and -KsB2mVkpgQe_fRyFFH4 are  auto generated so it's possible to have more values like that two.

I know how to solve that in android studio with Java code but I'm interesting about implementing server functions.

Comment: How can I access value endTime? var firebaseRefEndTime = firebase.database.ref('Events').child().child().val("endTime‌​"); I didn't put anything in that child brackets because it's autogenerated by my android app..I just need value from every endTime field.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is buried deep within Firebase [Database Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach). 
`forEach()` is used to get to the child without knowing the child's exact path.

```
var leadsRef = database.ref('leads');
leadsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    });
});
```

Now `childSnapshot` will contain the required data, the same thing can also be accessed using `child_added`.

```
leadsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      //Do something with the data
});
```

The only difference is that in case of `forEach()`, it will loop through from the start so if any new data will be added, it will also load the previous data but in case of `child_added`, the listener is only on new child and not the previous existing childs.

Useful Link:

[Firebase Read and Write Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can I access value endTime?
var firebaseRefEndTime = firebase.database.ref('Events').child().child().val("endTime");

I didn't put anything in that child brackets because it's autogenerated by my android app..I just need value from every endTime field..